# Is there a transparent theme?

Tags: frames, themes

I've been looking for themes which are transparent, but I didn't find any.
Is there someone who uses a transparent theme?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution, and no longer I need transparent theme.

The solution is :

```
;; set transparency
(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(85 85))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 85 85))
```

Comment: how do you put this into emacs? for someone new to emacs is this in a file somewhere or at a command?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't just change the background, but also makes text transparent as well.

Comment: Can you comment on what this code does, exactly? Why are there two parameters?

Answer (score 8):

You can set [transparency](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs) within Emacs by setting ['alpha](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html) frame parameter,

> This parameter specifies the opacity of the frame, on graphical displays that support variable opacity. It should be an integer between 0 and 100, where 0 means completely transparent and 100 means completely opaque. It can also have a nil value, which tells Emacs not to set the frame opacity (leaving it to the window manager).
>
> To prevent the frame from disappearing completely from view, the variable frame-alpha-lower-limit defines a lower opacity limit. If the value of the frame parameter is less than the value of this variable, Emacs uses the latter. By default, frame-alpha-lower-limit is 20.
>
> The alpha frame parameter can also be a cons cell (‘active’ . ‘inactive’), where ‘active’ is the opacity of the frame when it is selected, and ‘inactive’ is the opacity when it is not selected.

but **more general** solution is to use *your* [compositor manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager#List_of_compositing_window_managers).

For example with [Compton](https://github.com/chjj/compton) you can change Emacs’ (or any window) opacity with following change in Compton’s config (i.e. *~/.config/compton.conf* file):

```
opacity-rule = [ "90:class_g = 'Emacs'", # 10% of transparency
                 "90:!focused && class_g = 'Conkeror'"] # as a bonus
```

Solution will vary between operating systems and windowing systems ergo I’m providing this answer only FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

The current answers here are a bit outdated so I'll post more current information. The other methods *will* result in a blurred background, but the text will be blurred as well, impacting readability. I presume this is generally not desirable.
Fortunately, as of Emacs 29, there is a [method](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs#h5o-1) to blur only the background and leave the text opaque: using the frame parameter `alpha-background` instead of the more general frame parameter (mentioned in this question's other answers), `alpha`.
To do this, simply run `(set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha-background X)`, where '`X`' is whatever transparency percentage you desire.

Like all Emacs configuration, you must add it to your .emacs file for it to persist between sessions. The [previously linked wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs#h5o-1) provides ELisp code for this (it's identical to the code Vivian posted 9 years ago aside from the frame parameter*):

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha-background 70)
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha-background . 70))
```

and it worked nicely for me.

Some prerequisites for usage of the above:

- If you're on Wayland, you'll have to have the pure GTK (PGTK) package installed, claims the wiki. However, I found it worked out of the box for me using the normal `Emacs` package in the official Arch repository.
- Again, you must have Emacs version 29 or later

*the writer of the wiki article also has favoured the use of '`nil`' over '`(selected-window)`', but a quick `C-h f set-frame-parameter` will reveal that `set-frame-parameter` defaults to the selected frame if it supplied `nil` as an argument.